# Final Touches on a Slide Left and Right VueJs Transition

Tags: vue.js, transition, slideshow, slide

I have a slideshow built with VueJS, which can display or hide different slides depending on what buttons are pressed (with arrows and pagination). The core functionality of this slideshow is robust, but I am having a minor difficulty with applying transitions to the slide components.

Here's the transition group and its child components:

```
<transition-group :name="topicDirection ? 'topic-left' : 'topic-right'">
  <component v-for="(topic, index) in topics" :is="topic.component" :key="topic.title" 
    v-show="activeTopic === index"/>
</transition-group>
```

And here's the associated topic-left and topic-right classes in CSS:

```
.topic-left-enter-active,
.topic-left-leave-active,
.topic-right-enter-active,
.topic-right-leave-active {
    transition: all 3s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}

.topic-left-enter,
.topic-right-leave-to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

.topic-right-enter,
.topic-left-leave-to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.topic-left-enter,
.topic-left-leave-to,
.topic-right-enter,
.topic-right-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
 }
```

What this is giving me so far is a slide-right with the intended animation, and a slide-left with unusual animation, like so:

[image]

Whilst the slide-right animation hides the previous topic and moves the new topic right as it increases in opacity within three seconds, the slide-left animation moves the previous topic to the left as it loses opacity in three seconds, then waits another three seconds before showing the new topic already in place.

The intended effect for the slide-left animation is an approximate mirror of that of slide-right - the previous topic should disappear and the new topic should slide left as it increases in opacity, like so:

[image]

I feel like this is likely a simple fix, but I am struggling with the logic somewhat and am still quite new to VueJS, and appreciate the guidance this site offers. If any part of this question needs clarification then please ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get the same effect for left and right using the following:

```
    .topic-left-enter {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    }

.topic-right-enter {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    }

.topic-left-enter-active,
.topic-right-enter-active {
    transition: all 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
    }
```

For whatever reason, the leave transition classes were interfering with both the right and left transitions - probably worth looking into in the future, but for the time being I'm content with this solution.